# expectation conditioned on sigma fields

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

could anyone please explain to me a simple  question regarding expectations conditioned on sigma fields?

Consider a sample space {a, b, c} and $F_1$ = $\sigma$(a) and $F_2$ = $\sigma$(b) and a random variable X. X(a) = X(b) = 1 and X(c) = 0.

How do I calculate E(X|$F_1$) and E(E(X|$F_1$)|$F_2$) respectively and why? Thanks!

Comment: What have youtried?

Comment: The statement that [a belongs to F1] is absurd and signals that you should (1) check the general definition of a sigma-algebra on a set and (2) modify accordingly your view of what F1 and F2 are. Furthermore you forgot to indicate the probability measure P on {a,b,c}.

Comment: {a} is not a subset of F1.

Comment: What you just explained is that {a} is an **element** of F1.

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is uniform, then 
$$E(X\mid F_1)=\frac12+\frac12\mathbf 1_{\{a\}},\qquad E(E(X\mid F_1)\mid F_2)=\frac34-\frac14\mathbf 1_{\{b\}}.$$